Fast way to compute the largest eigenvector of an expensive-to-compute matrix
Consider an $N \times N$ Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix $M$. Computing the elements of $M$ is expensive so we wish to compute as few as possible. We can assume that $M$ can be approximated as a low rank matrix such that its rank $r \ll N$.
I am interested in calculating only the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $M$. What is the fastest way to do this that requires as few elements of $M$ to be calculated?
So far, I am thinking of using the skeleton decomposition (e.g. see https://advancedoptimizationatharvard.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/skeleton-decomposition/), but that seems to be overkill because this gives me a good approximation for $M$, while I only want a good approximation the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. Any ideas?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Could you link to a definition of the skeleton decomposition of matrices?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

On first thought, the computation of a "few elements" of $M$ doesn't seem to guarantee much in the way of a good approximation to its largest eigenvalue, so perhaps the repeated emphasis on "largest eigenvector" (or an eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue?) is significant.   In some applications it might be possible to compute a matrix-vector product $Mv$ without directly producing the entries of $M$.  This in turn suggests the "power method" that @WillJagy referenced.

Power iteration or Arnoldi iteration should work well if you can get a good approximation of the matrix-vector product

Yes, indeed I meant the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. I have now added that in an edit.

By skeleton decomposition, I mean this: https://advancedoptimizationatharvard.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/skeleton-decomposition/

Hi, the power iteration method looks like it's a possible solution, but how do I efficiently evaluate M.v without evaluating all the elements of M? (Evaluating all elements of M is expensive so I want to evaluate as few elements of M as possible. This should be possible because M is low rank).

Please don't put the link/clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to incorporate this information into the question -- e.g., link to the definition in the question itself.
